# Sort Lock columns in EPplus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm using EPPlus to generate Excel workbooks.

I'm trying to figure out how to sort locked and unlocked columns.

Appreciate your help! Thank you much

Comment: I think this is more of an excel problem then epplus.  AFAIK the only way to do it would be to unlock the cells - sort - and relock.  Or use a macro:  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/sorting-locked-cells/5d2a1bd1-661d-4940-9547-f4cd90d2164b

Comment: Thank you so much!